# How to add ng-bootstrap to an Angular-CLI (Broccoli version) project?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

How to add `ng-bootstrap` (by written by the angular-ui team) to an Angular-CLI (Angular2 RC4) project?

More specifically:

1. How should I add the minified `.css` from my `node_modules` folder to my angular-cli project?
2. Do I have to add it to `angular-cli-build.js`?
3. Do I have to add the typings?
4. Do I have to add it to `/src/system-config.ts`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you have to add all of your css files by referencing from vendorNpmFiles in `angular-cli-build.js` file
First go to the project directory and type

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

then open your angular-cli-build.js and add this line

```
 vendorNpmFiles: [
  'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
  'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
  'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
  'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
  'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(ts|js|js.map)',
  'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
  '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
  'angularfire2/**/*.js',
  'firebase/*.js',
  '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/**/*.+(js|js.map)'
]
```

now open your src/system-config.ts, write

```
const map: any = {
  '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': 'vendor/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'
};
```

and

```
const packages: any = {
  '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': {
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'index.js'
  },
  '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/accordion': {
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'index.js'
  },
  '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/alert': {
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'index.js'
  },
  '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/buttons': {
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'index.js'
  },
  '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/carousel': {
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'index.js'
  },
  '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/collapse': {
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'index.js'
  },
  '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/dropdown': {
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'index.js'
  },
  '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/pagination': {
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'index.js'
  },
  '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/popover': {
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'index.js'
  },
  '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/progressbar': {
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'index.js'
  },
  '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/rating': {
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'index.js'
  },
  '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/tabset': {
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'index.js'
  },
  '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/timepicker': {
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'index.js'
  },
  '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/tooltip': {
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'index.js'
  },
  '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/typeahead': {
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'index.js'
  }
};
```

Comment: Edited the answer because it is asking for ng-bootstrap written by angular ui team. It's not asking about ng2-bootstrap by Valore Software. See here for differences. https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/4s3kkx/what_is_the_difference_between_ngbootstrap/

Comment: @pd-farhad when i set `precompile: [ NGB_PRECOMPILE ]` i got the following error: bootstrap-angular/tmp/broccoli_type_script_compiler-input_base_path-djYaKive.tmp/0/src/app/app.component.ts (8, 3): Argument of type '{ moduleId: string; selector: string; directives: (typeof NgbAlert | typeof NgbDismissibleAlert)[...' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ selector?: string; inputs?: string[]; outputs?: string[]; properties?: string[]; events?: strin...'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'precompile' does not exist in type '{ selector?: string; inputs?: string[]; outp

Answer (score 2):

Yes well answered by @pd farhad above but I want to give some explanation to that one,

Actually if you have to add some third party libraries in **angular CLI** then you must have to add that third party library reference in the **angular-cli-build.js** file , because angular cli took all files from the vendor folder instead of `node_modules` folder so whenever you add entry for your library (say ng-bootstrap in your case) in cli-build file. it will make copy of that library in the vendor folder of angular cli. which is available to our project. so

> How should I add the minified .css from my node_modules folder to my angular-cli project?

you have to give reference of that file/library in the `system-cli-build.js` file in order to get in the vendor folder.

> Do I have to add it to angular-cli-build.js

yes, its compulsory if it is a library, but not in case of a just single file then you can drop that file into public folder too. its depends on you.

> Do I have to add the typings?

Not that much compulsory.

hope this clears more!

Comment: Very well explained. Appreciates this explanation so much. May I know why it's Not that much compulsory to add to typings? Adding AngularFire2 requires adding to typings. So what is the deciding factor to add to typings or not?

Comment: Thanks a lot your appreciation means a lot for me :) sorry I have no solid idea about that whenever I come to know I'll post or edit in my existing answer