# Precompile fails when adding ng-bootstrap to an Angular-CLI project

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng-bootstrap

When i try to add ng-bootstrap to Angular-CLI project according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/38413274/1596547, i can't not use the `procompile option`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {NGB_ALERT_DIRECTIVES,NGB_PRECOMPILE} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  directives: [ NGB_ALERT_DIRECTIVES ],
  precompile: [ NGB_PRECOMPILE ],
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
  public isCollapsed:boolean = false;
}
```

The above generates the following error:

```
Error: Typescript found the following errors:
  /home/bass/testdrive/bootstrap-angular/tmp/broccoli_type_script_compiler-input_base_path-tcvIrPf2.tmp/0/src/app/app.component.ts (9, 3): Argument of type '{ moduleId: string; selector: string; directives: (typeof NgbAlert | typeof NgbDismissibleAlert)[...' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ selector?: string; inputs?: string[]; outputs?: string[]; properties?: string[]; events?: strin...'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'precompile' does not exist in type '{ selector?: string; inputs?: string[]; outputs?: string[]; properties?: string[]; events?: strin...'.
```

Comment: This seems like a version issue. precompile was added in rc4... https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/6c5b653

Comment: @Brocco thanks! you're right about that updating to Angular2 RC4 solved the issue. If you like you can post it as an answer, so i can mark the question as solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a version issue. precompile was added in rc4

via this commit: github.com/angular/angular/commit/6c5b653

rc4 changelog: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md (look under features)