# Error when adding the NGB_ALERT_DIRECTIVES from ng-bootstrap to an Angular-CLI project

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng-bootstrap

I try to to add the alert directive (NGB_ALERT_DIRECTIVES) of ng-bootstrap to an Angular-CLI project. I followed the steps described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38413274/1596547.

The preceding results in the following error:

```
EXCEPTION: Can't resolve all parameters for NgbDismissibleAlert: (TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef, Injector, ?, Renderer).
```

How to fix the above and is it related to the precompile option? See: [Precompile fails when adding ng-bootstrap to an Angular-CLI project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38696508/precompile-fails-when-adding-ng-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to the version of angular, updating angular to Angular2 RC4 solved it.

In the in the `package.json` of angular-cli use the following dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.8",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.1",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.0.24",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.26",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
  },
```

Run `npm update` and the issue is solved. The error was not related to the precompile option.